# SelectListItem : Selected never true

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried many things and i never get a "true" for the attribute Selected of a SelectListItem .
Even with this simple code :

```
        List<SelectListItem> _LiList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        item2.Selected = true;
        item2.Text = "blabla";
        item2.Value = "ho";
        _LiList.Add(item2);
        SelectList selectlist = new SelectList(_LiList, "Value", "Text");
```

I still get a "false" when i inspect "selectlist" in debug mode... But if i inspect "_LiList" i can see the "Selected : true"   T_T

Anyone have an idea? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the item to be selected when it loads initially using the following overload.

[SelectList overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IList<Item> your_item_source = item_source.GetItems.ToList<Item>();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList =
from item in your_item_source
select new SelectListItem
{
Selected = true,
Text = item.item_name,
Value = item.item_id.ToString()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `selected` inside `SelectList`. Find index of `Item2` in `_LiList` list:

```
List<SelectListItem> _LiList = new List<SelectListItem>();

item2.Text = "blabla";
item2.Value = "ho";
_LiList.Add(item2);

SelectList selectlist = new SelectList(_LiList, "Value", "Text", _LiList.IndexOf(item2));
```